# Ansible: Dynamic AWS inventory with groups

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ansible

I have setup a mixed (static and dynamic aws) inventory inside my ansible folder.

```
$ ls inventory/
ec2.ini
ec2.py
inventory.yml
```

The configuration for that is as follows:

```
$ grep 'inventory' ansible.cfg
hostfile = ./inventory
inventory_ignore_extensions = .ini, .pyc, .pyo, .retry
```

My static inventory has hosts grouped via the `ini-style` directives. e.g.:

```
[webservers]
host1.domain.tld
host2.domain.tld
host3.domain.tld

[database]
host4.domain.tld
host5.domain.tld
host6.domain.tld
```

How can I group hosts in my dynamic inventory?

Comment: Off topic: inventory.yml is wrong. The ansible inventory has ini format not yaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using an `dynamic inventory` with Ansible hosts can be grouped and addressed by using `tags` like this:

```
---
- hosts: tag_Ansible_Slave
  user: ec2-user
  become: True
  tasks:
   - name: Update all packages to latest
     yum: name=* state=latest
```

[patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) can be used to define hosts based on the combination, intersection, etc of ec2 tags, like this: `tag_webservers:&tag_Ansible_Slave`

Tags can be set with Ansible with the [ec2 module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html) with the `instance_tags` parameter when initializing the instances in AWS.

You might want to checkout this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/?adbid=562667719041245185&adbpl=tw&adbpr=192929401&adbsc=APN_Blog_20150203_39862237) for further instructions.